# Can task pane bars insert iFrame elements into Powerpoint Online?

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I've looked at the Office Dev Center and Napa documentation, but this is still unclear to me. This link:

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

Has a "Word, Excel, and PowerPoint Add-ins that extend functionality" section with task bars and a "Excel and PowerPoint add-ins that create new objects" section, implying that task bars do not create new objects; is this the case?

Comment: I want to make a new Napa task bar add-on, and I'm following this tutorial:

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-with-napa

Whenever I select "run" on the app, it opens in Excel; how do we make it open in Powerpoint Online? I've gone to the "Run" tab where we can select where we want to run the app, but the other options cannot be selected; it says that I need to download Visual Basic, but then when I try to download Visual Basic, the files don't run on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "iframe" you're describing is a "content add-in", which is a rectangular control than goes on the slide canvas and can show your HTML/JS UI. It's not possible to insert these from a button on the task pane today. If you need this kind of "iframe", simply write a content add-in: your users can insert as many instances of this content add-in as they want per slide.

If you need a task pane **and** web content in the slide today, then it's necessary to write (and ship) two separate add-ins: one for the task pane "shape" and the other for the content "shape".

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use Napa to make a content add-in for Powerpoint Online, but it only lets me make it for Excel Online. A message says that "Content add-in are not supported in PowerPoint 2013 RTM"

Comment: Can you suggest the best way to develop and ship a content add-in for Powerpoint Online, using a Mac?

Comment: Also, is it possible for the content add-in to have a login feature that accesses data from an external source?

Comment: Content add-ins in PowerPoint are available in Office 2013 (RTM means it wasn't updated, but normally 2013-users will have downloaded the service packs through Microsoft Update automatically. If you want to test the add-in on a Mac you can sideload it: http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac